# Java check mouse button state

Tags: java, events, swing

How can I check the state of the mouse buttons in Java? I cannot use mouse events, as it involves getting 'mouse released' on an element that has never received 'mouse pressed', so I theoretically could use events if it intercepted mouse events system wide, but that would probably be a security risk. If I can't do this with java, I am happy to write a native interface, and I am developing on Mac 10.6.

Comment: AFAIK mouseReleased() actually gets called on the same element that originally received mousePressed(). Even if not, you can always have a boolean to track whether an element was pressed so you know how to deal with release

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three words:

[Global Event Listeners](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/08/30/global-event-listeners/)