# JScrollpane mouseListener

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, mouselistener

I hava a JScrollPane used to dram structures(diagrams) and I want to invoke a method every time user releases mouse click in this JScrollPane drawing area. 
I used

```
yourJScrollPane.getViewport().getView().addMouseListener(yourMouseListener);
```

as per given here [Use JScrollPane mouse listener over viewport components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11478147/use-jscrollpane-mouse-listener-over-viewport-components)

This works. On every mouse release the desired method is invoked which updates the JTable in the GUI.
But, the problem is, the diagram which user draws moves all around the JScrollPane's available drawing/edit window area. For every click the drawing moves to a new place. If I remove the JScrollPane mouseListener, the structure does not move.
Is there any other way I can listen to the JScrollPane clicks and the view(diagrams) is not affected?
Thank you for the inputs.

**Edit:**

```
  JScrollPane jScrolPane = (JScrollPane)(((JPanel) readyPanel.getComponent(1)).getComponent(0));
  jScrolPane.getViewport().addMouseListener(new calculateDimensions(readyPanel, propertiesTable));
```

Here, `readyPanel` is a panel I receive from another method which is all stuffed with tool bars and JScrollPane.
I am trying to get the JScrollPane from this stuffed JPanel and invoke the method to calculate dimensions.

Comment: Please provide a [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thank you guys. I fixed it. There was no problem with JScrollPane. I had an extra code snippet which was causing the movement of the drawing.