# Unable to add key listener to shift number for my No. shifting app via button in swing Java

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, keyboard-events, keylistener

I'm trying to write code for number shifting application using swing gui 
     in java. however, I'm stuck at shifting number from one button to another 
     using arrow keys. Arrow keys doesn't respond. Java code for shifting number 
     through buttons via arrow key. no luck. the keys do not respond. Currently 
     i'm done with random number generation whenever the start button is 
     pressed. however, I want to use the arrow keys to navigate through the 
     buttons to shift the numbers accordingly.

> I'm pretty new to this, but I'm unable to utilize the keylistener interface for getting the desired result. There are no errors, however, the key isn't responding

```
frame.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() 
    {
        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

            int j = 0;
            int temp;
            int i = 0;
            int k = 0;
            boolean zeroFound = false;
            int code = e.getKeyCode();

            if (code == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) 
            {
                for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) 
                {
                    for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) 
                    {
                        if (arr[i][j] == 0) 
                        {
                            zeroFound = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if (zeroFound == true) 
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (j == 0) 
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please enter valid arrow key:)");
                }
                else
                {
                    temp = arr[i][j];
                    arr[i][j] = arr[i][j-1];
                    arr[i][j-1] = temp;

                    for (int a = 0; i < 4; a++) 
                    {
                        for (int b = 0; j < 4; b++) 
                        {                       
                            JButton button[] = {button1, button2, button3,button4,button5,button6,
                                    button7, button8,button9,button10,button11,button12, button13,
                                    button14, button15, button16};  

                            if (arr[i][j] !=0) 
                                {

                                    int n = arr[i][j];                              
                                    button[k].setText(String.valueOf(n));
                                    k++;

                                }
                                else {
                                    button[k].setText(" ");
                                }

                        }
                    }


                }
            }
        }

    });
```

Comment: As with almost all `KeyListener` related issues - use the [key bindings API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) instead

Comment: If your goal is to take game-like control over all input of your window, you'd probably prefer to use an [AWTEventListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8586098/global-event-listeners-with-awteventlistener-how-to-pull-mouseevents-from-it).

Comment: Key Bindings API works perfectly well. Thanks for the responses:);  And yes, KeyListener can be frustrating.